# "Count()" after "Take()" on "IQueryable" returns wrong result?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, iqueryable

After performing `take(n)` linq method on *IQueriable* data (initial count `m`), method `Count()` still returns `m` value.

Is performing `ToList()` command is the only option to get actual count from *IQueryable*?

```
var data = service.Get();//100 records
var data2 = data.Take(10);

var count = data2.count(); //result 100 - wrong
var count2 = data2.ToList().Count; // result 10 - correct
```

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: So, where is your code?

Comment: What do you mean by "still returns m value"? IQueriable.Take() is not going to take an object out of the initial IQueriable like "take a cookie out of the cookie jar".

Comment: Hmm, the code was there until someone made a botched edit.

Comment: @sebingel I thought It should be applied before count() in expression tree

Comment: Ah okay. Now i get it. But this is weird. count and count 2 should be the same...

Comment: It's a bug in the query provider (or unsupported feature).  Not much to do, other than ask the query provider to fix it, or avoid the situation.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the LINQ calls, but the SQL generated by NHibernate may not do what you think it does. Check the queries that actually get generated by each call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use ToList() for this case, or find an alternative solution, or cap the result of Count() yourself (since the correct value can never be larger than the value specified to Take()).

Known bug in NHibernate:
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2477